# Is the sentence, “He’s too easily prone to pouts and feuds” grammatically right?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

There was the following passage in the New York Times (January 30) article written by Maureen Dowd under the headline “Here’s the beauty of Trump.”:

> “He rejects the idea that he’s too easily swayed by compliments or
>   slights, too easily **prone to pouts and feuds**.
>
> “Putin said Donald Trump was absolutely brilliant and would win the
>   election,” he said. “My rival wanted me to disavow it. The head of
>   Russia calls me brilliant and you want me to disavow it? **What are you
>   smoking?”**

I took ‘pout’ and ‘feud’ for verbs after ‘prone to’ off hand, because I'm used to associate "prone" to "be prone to do" usage. Do we need ‘s’ after ‘pout’ and ‘feud’ instead of infinitive form?  Or else, are they nouns in plural form?

Additionally, what does “What are you smoking?” mean? Does it mean “Are you crazy because of smoking marijuana or drug”?

Comment: You got it right, twice. Both _pouts_ and _feuds_ are nouns in their plural forms, and _What are you smoking?_ is a rhetorical question that could be paraphrased as: _Are you high or drugs or something?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *to* in the idiom "to *be prone to*" could be both a *preposition* and the *to* in to-infinitive. Only way to tell is to see whether a noun or bare-infinitive follows it, e.g., two plural nouns follow the *to* in your example sentence and we can tell the *to* is a preposition.

To be [prone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prone) to means:

> (prone to **a noun**/**to do** something) Likely or liable to suffer from, do, or
>   experience something unpleasant or regrettable: '*farmed fish are prone
>   to disease*'.

The nouns [*pout*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pout) and [*feud*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feud) are countable nouns and they were used because Trump causes multiple pouts and feuds by making controversial and derogatory comments or statements.

"What are you smoking?" literally means "what kind of [smokable drugs](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1360-0443.1997.tb02934.x/pdf) are you taking?" There are many types of drugs that could be smoked, e.g., heroine, phencyclidine (PCP), cocaine, amphetamines, marijuana and opium, etc.

"What are you smoking?" could be rephrased to

> Are you crazy? (I don't have any reason to disavow what Putin said
>   about me.)

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: *Prone* can take an infinitive.  Try the google on the phrase "prone to drink too much" for posts on alcoholism.  "Prone to pout and feud" would be liable to perform two actions; "prone to pouts and feuds" would be liable to end up with results of those two actions.

Comment: @deadrat Yes, that's what is said on the copied definition. Maybe I was not clear enough. I will edit my post.